# My jenkinsfile that uses a Docker agent hangs when being executed in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, freeze

I am running Jenkins 2.190.1 installed on a Linux Ubuntu LTD 18.04. I just tested the sample code in the Jenkins Guided Tour: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/

In concrete my Jenkinsfile is as follows:

```
    pipeline {
        agent { docker { image 'maven:3.3.3' } }
        stages {
           stage('build') {
                steps {
                    sh 'mvn --version'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the output that I receive in the jenkins console log:

```
$ docker run -t -d -u 122:127 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tutorial -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tutorial:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tutorial:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tutorial@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tutorial@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** maven:3-alpine cat
$ docker top f7771c51c24b1a4d283f327c2ac26959f649f253778f53d65caa94edb0f35cfc -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tutorial@tmp/durable-74c26f6c
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 f7771c51c24b1a4d283f327c2ac26959f649f253778f53d65caa94edb0f35cfc
$ docker rm -f f7771c51c24b1a4d283f327c2ac26959f649f253778f53d65caa94edb0f35cfc
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -2
Finished: FAILURE
```